# Range of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - x +1}$

Tags: functions

How can we find the range of $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2 - x +1}$?

I know the fact that

> Range of $ax^2 + bx + c$ is $[\dfrac{-D}{4a}, \infty)$ when a >0

> Range of $ax^2 + bx +c $ is $(- \infty, \dfrac{-D}{4a}]$ when a < 0.

My doubt is that using the above method I'm able to find the range of the given function and also I'm able to find range from graph, but I'm interested in finding it's range using any other fundamental method which would be applicable for my subjective exam. Is there any other method?

I also know that finding the domain of inverse function could find the range of the given function but it is also not working in this case.

Comment: The fundamental idea would be to start with $y=f(x)$ and to try to manipulate that equation into the form $x=...$. In the course of doing that you will find out that some restrictions must hold for the values of $y$ in order for the equation to be possible. These restrictions basically give you the range (the range are all the values $y$ for which an $x$ exists so that the above equation holds). For example, $0$ is not in the range of $f$

Comment: Talking about "Range of $ax^2 + bx +c =0 $" is nonsense because $ax^2 + bx +c =0 $ is not a _function_ (it's an _equation_). You meant "Range of $ax^2 + bx +c $".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$x^2-x+1=\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34,$$the range of $x^2-x+1$ is $\left[\frac34,\infty\right)$, and therefore the range of your function is $\left(0,\frac43\right]$.